# Incident field as limit of diffracted field, for a close screen

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

Imagine a beam with field $E(\rho',0)$ incident on an aperture at $z=0$. 
 We observe the diffracted field $E(\rho)$ on a screen at a distance $z$.

In the paraxial regime & Fresnel diffraction, the resultant diffracted field is given by the *Fresnel-Kirchhoff* formula (a derivation of which can be found [here](http://physlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Diffraction-Ch10.pdf)).

In cylindrical coordinates, this reduces to:

$$ E(\rho,z) = -\frac{2\pi i e^{ikz} e^{i\frac{k \rho^2}{2 z}}}{\lambda z} \int_{\text{aperture}} \rho' \, \mathrm{d}\rho'\,E(\rho',0)\,J_0 \left (\frac{k \rho\,\rho'}{z} \right) .$$

As $z\rightarrow0$, i.e. as I move the screen closer and closer to the aperture, I expect the integral should simpify to just $E(\rho',0)$.

However, as $z\rightarrow0$, the denominator of the pre-factor blows up!

I know that $\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$ is not 100% correct as the propagation factor for the wavelets, since the full solution to the wave equation also contains a $\propto r^{l}$ term...

But can I recover $E(\rho',0)$ as $z\rightarrow 0$ somehow?

---

(Motivation: I want to plot the radial profile of $E(\rho',0)$ as a function of $z$ to see how the beam evolves depending on the optical components that I put in its way. Ideally at $z=0$ I would like to see the same input field)

Comment: I have not done the math, but there might some hope of rewriting that expression for small $z$ in the form one of those representations of the delta function. Something like $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{2 \pi z}}\exp\left[i \frac{k}{2z} (\rho-\rho')^2\right]$ which goes to $\delta(\rho-\rho')$ when $z \rightarrow 0$. Use the proper expansion for $J_0$ and pick the dominant contributions to see if this is possible.

Comment: Also, notice that this expression is what they obtain after performing both the Fresnel and more importantly the Fraunhofer approximation. This means this is explicitly supposed to be used for large $z$. I think with equation 10.27 you have better chances of reproducing the delta behavior I mentioned, as opposed to 10.28. Still, 10.27 assumes $R$ and $z$ to be of the same order so ultimately, for your intentions, take that into account and see if this computation will be good enough.

Comment: There is Fraunhofer approximation here. And the Frensel approximation only means we are looking at forward propagating beams,  and paraxial approximation.

Comment: Right. That's why I say that you'll have a better chance of reproducing $E(\rho)$ for $z \rightarrow 0$ with equation 10.27, which is obtained before applying the Fraunhofer approximation.